# how to obtain a stack trace when WAMP server crashes?

Tags: php, crash, stack-trace, wamp

Some times my WAMP server crashes . I get the following error.

```
HTTP has encountered exception and needs to close.
Unreferenced Memory.
szAppName : httpd.exe     szAppVer : 2.2.11.0     szModName : php5ts.dll     
szModVer : 5.3.0.0     offset : 0000c309     


C:\DOCUME~1\blrcom\LOCALS~1\Temp\WERc677.dir00\httpd.exe.mdmp
C:\DOCUME~1\blrcom\LOCALS~1\Temp\WERc677.dir00\appcompat.txt
```

My question is how to obtain stack trace to debug this problem ? 
Should I use a windows debugger [windows debugger](http://windowscoding.com/blogs/blake/archive/2009/05/12/opening-a-mini-dump-file-mdmp-file-with-WinDbg.aspx)
or is there some setting in WAMP server configuration should i enable ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Debug Diag](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=28BD5941-C458-46F1-B24D-F60151D875A3&displaylang=en).
Select the "Crash" rule in the "Select Rule Type" dialog that pops up when you start Debug Diag.

Also take a look at Tess Ferrandez blog entry [Debugging Native memory leaks with Debug Diag 1.1](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/archive/2010/01/14/debugging-native-memory-leaks-with-debug-diag-1-1.aspx). (Though it's not exactly about what you want, it's *never* wrong to read that blog ;-))

---

Debug Symbols contain information that "glue" the executable and the code together. Microsoft's format for debug symbols is called "program database" and they are usually stored in files having the extension `.pdb`.
Right now you only get "the assembly instruction at php5ts!zend_mm_shutdown+f69". The application called into a function `zend_mm_shutdown` that is exported by the php5ts.dll, so the debugger "knows" about this function regardless of whether there are debug symbols or not. But it doesn't know about the source code that led the compiler to build the machine instruction at zend_mm_shutdown+f69. The debug symbols contain such information, so a debugger can show you the source code and the context.
You can create debug symbols for both the debug and the release build (for the latter they are usually less accurate). But I haven't found a debug pack for the wamp builds of php.
For the php.net/win32 build you can download the debug packs for their release builds from http://windows.php.net/download/. Or you can download the source code and create a debug build yourself. But you can't mix the wamp executable with the php.net debug packs (i.e. you wouldn't use the the wamp executables/dlls for this).

And maybe seeing the source code can give you a hint about what's going wrong. But somehow I doubt that. The mm in `zend_mm_shutdown` probably stands for "memory management". It probably just releases some buckets of memory and some of its data structures are wrong *at this point*. That could be some other code overwriting data of the zend memory management. Could be an edge case that is handled wrong (something that has been freed but not removed from the list/data structure). The bad thing is the underlying problem could be anywhere   ...far, far away from the code that is finally causing the access violation. And if `zend_mm_shutdown` really is some low-level memory management there's probably not much information left about what changed the data structure (and why).
I'd rather try another php build first and see if the problem occurs again. It shouldn't be to hard to replace the wamp files by the php.net build. It might be as easy as to replace the php folder in your wamp installation and then look if you have to copy some files to the apache binary folder, too.
But make a copy/backup of the complete wamp folder first  ....just in case ;-)

Comment: I am getting the following log. What should i do with this ?

WARNING - DebugDiag was not able to locate debug symbols for php5ts.dll, so the information below may be incomplete.



In httpd__PID__16220__Date__03_20_2010__Time_01_20_53PM__269__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at php5ts!zend_mm_shutdown+f69 in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin\php5ts.dll from The PHP Group has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x0000000c on thread 17

Comment: zend\_mm\_shutdown ...that's used for cleaning up the php instance (after a request has been served). You could replace the WAMP-build of php by the php.net build and try again.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply. It would be great if you can answer these
1)  Debug Diag was not able to locate symbols? What is this ?
2) Is there any way I can know which script is causing it ? Becasuse I have somemany scripts running.
Are there settings in this software which can give me more details ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elaborate reply. I found a debug pack for the WAMP version . After a few days the apache server did crash. Here are the logs .

In httpd__PID__3428__Date__03_31_2010__Time_06_52_50PM__777__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at php5ts!_zend_mm_free_int+139 in C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.11\bin\php5ts.dll from The PHP Group has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x0000000c on thread 61

Answer (score 0):

Please see the logs below from the tool debug diagnostics tool with php 5.3.0  debug pack. 
Is it problem with PDO library that is used to access MySql ??
The crash is very intermittent. Please reply.

Thread 61 - System ID 2760
Entry point   msvcrt!_endthreadex+3a 
Create time   3/31/2010 5:25:46 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:16.593 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.453

Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3   Source 
php5ts!_zend_mm_free_int+139     0288a878     00020004     008eff46
php5ts!_efree+36     0110ff48     02d18868     0090e442
php5ts!_zval_ptr_dtor+66     024ffa88     02d18770     02d18848
php5ts!zend_std_write_property+1f2     02d18848     0110ff48     02d18868
php5ts!pdo_stmt_construct+7d     02d1b968     02d18848     0110eb90
php5ts!zim_PDO_prepare+428     0110eb90     02d18848     00000000
php5ts!zend_do_fcall_common_helper_SPEC+946     024ffbf8     028894c8     024ffe74
php5ts!execute+29e     02d40070     02889400     00000000
php5ts!zend_execute_scripts+f6     00000008     028894c8     00000000
php5ts!php_execute_script+22d     024ffe74     028894c8     00000005
php5apache2_2!php_handler+5d0     03249f98     008238b8     03249f98
libhttpd!ap_run_handler+21     03249f98     03249f98     03249f98
libhttpd!ap_invoke_handler+ae     00000000     029e9fd8     024fff38
libhttpd!ap_die+29e     03249f98     00000000     00788168
libhttpd!ap_get_request_note+1c9c     029e9fd8     029e9fd8     029e9fd8
libhttpd!ap_run_process_connection+21     029e9fd8     00775050     024fff80
libhttpd!ap_process_connection+33     029e9fd8     027de3f0     00ed0000
libhttpd!ap_regkey_value_remove+c7c     029e9fd0     00ed0000     00f10000
msvcrt!_endthreadex+a9     011d3088     00ed0000     00f10000
kernel32!BaseThreadStart+37     77c3a341     011d3088     00000000

Comment: It looks like pdo->prepare crashes (actually efree, but the last thing _you_ call in your php script is pdo->prepare). I'd really try the php.net win32 build.

Comment: Ok I will try with the latest php build and update you . Thanks a lot for your inputs .